# why bootstrap modal video start on page refresh?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

why video is playing on page refresh please help me out regarding this,i have tried everything which i know i only wnat to keep video played when modal is clicked but it playing on first page refresh.

```
    <div class="bs-example">
    <!-- Button HTML (to Trigger Modal) -->
    <a href="#myModal" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-toggle="modal">Launch Demo Modal</a>

    <!-- Modal HTML -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">YouTube Video</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <iframe id="cartoonVideo" width="560" height="315" src="1.mp4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>    
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    /* Get iframe src attribute value i.e. YouTube video url
    and store it in a variable */
    var url = $("#cartoonVideo").attr('src');

    /* Assign empty url value to the iframe src attribute when
    modal hide, which stop the video playing */
    $("#myModal").on('hide.bs.modal', function(){
        $("#cartoonVideo").attr('src', '');
    });

    /* Assign the initially stored url back to the iframe src
    attribute when modal is displayed again */
    $("#myModal").on('show.bs.modal', function(){
        $("#cartoonVideo").attr('src', url);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You can use `video` tag instead of `iframe` and disable autoplay.

Comment: check out http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_preload.asp and disable preload

Comment: hii makshh thanks for your great help its work when i apply video tag which you told but when i close modal and again open the modal video is playing if i click on play button only one time whenn i open modal then only video get played second time its not playing.